# spring data jpa unnecessary left join

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following model:

[image]

I want to get all `Institutions` (Intituciones) with specified `sectorId`.

In the `tbInstitucion` model I have a relationship with `tbSector`:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="`sectorId`")
 private Sector sector;
```

is there a way to obtain a query like:

```
select * 
from tbInstitucion 
where sectorId = ?
```

I tried with: `findBySector(Sector sector)`

but with this I need an additional query to find the sector and `findBySector` is generating the following query:

```
select
        generatedAlias0.institucionId,
        generatedAlias0.institucionNombre 
    from
        Institucion as generatedAlias0 
    left join
        generatedAlias0.sector as generatedAlias1 
    where
        generatedAlias1=:param0
```

tried with this other one:

```
findBySector_sectorId
```

which generates the above query as well.

Wouldn't be better to form a query like:

```
select * 
from tbInstitucion 
where sectorId = ?
```

Is there a way to get the above query? 
Why is JPA generating the left join?

Answer (score 10):

> A quick review of the entity model

```
@Entity
class Institucion {
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="`sectorId`")
  private Sector sector;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
@Entity
class Institucion {
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {}
             , fetch=FetchType.LAZY
             , optional = true
             , targetEntity = void.class)
  @JoinColumn(columnDefinition = ""
             , foreignKey = @ForeignKey
             , insertable = true
             , name="`sectorId`"
             , nullable = true
             , referencedColumnName = ""
             , table = ""
             , unique = false
             , updatable = false)
  private Sector sector;
}
```

Note `@ManyToOne(optional = true)` and `@JoinColumn(nullable = true)`. This signifies to the ORM that the `sector` attribute of `Institucion` is optional and may not be set (to a non-null value) all the time.

---

> How the entity model impacts repository queries

Now consider the following repository:

```
public interface InstitucionRepository extends CrudRepository<Institucion, Long> {
  List<Institucion> findAllByInstitucionNombre(String nombre);

  List<Institucion> findAllByInstitucionEmail(String email);
}
```

Given the entity declaration above, the repository methods should produce queries such as:

```
select
    generatedAlias0 
from
    Institucion as generatedAlias0 
left join
    generatedAlias0.sector as generatedAlias1 
where
    generatedAlias0.institucionNombre=:param0
```

and

```
select
    generatedAlias0 
from
    Institucion as generatedAlias0 
left join
    generatedAlias0.sector as generatedAlias1 
where
    generatedAlias0.institucionEmail=:param0
```

This is because the entity model indicates `sector` to be optional so the ORM needs to load `Institucion`s without worrying about their `sector`s.

Following this pattern, the following repository method:

```
  List<Institucion> findAllBySector(Sector sector);
```

translates to:

```
select
    generatedAlias0 
from
    Institucion as generatedAlias0 
left join
    generatedAlias0.sector as generatedAlias1 
where
    generatedAlias1=:param0
```

---

> **Solution 1**

If `Institucion.sector` is not optional, make it mandatory in the model too:

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name="`sectorId`", nullable = false)
  private Sector sector;
```

> **Solution 2**

If `Institucion.sector` is indeed optional, only a manual query such as the one shown in @MaciejKowalski's answer will work.

---

> Simplified query

The following query will also work:

```
  List<Institucion> findAllBySectorSectorId(Long id);
```

This assumes that the model attribute names are exactly as shown in the post.

Comment: Hi I did the same what you have suggested but I am still getting the same issue.

@MapsId("subscriptionId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_alert_subscription",nullable = false)

Answer (score 2):

Left join is a default implicit joining strategy, also when using the `@EntityGraph` feature.

I would recommend using explicit `@Query` definition:

```
@Query("select i from institution i inner join i.sector s where s.id = :sectorId")
public Institution getBySector(@Param("sectorId") Integer sectorId);
```

Comment: But why is it generating a join, wouldn't be better a select * from tbInstitucion where sectorId = ?

Comment: Thats not how you write queries in orm.. you get the dependent entity.. then you get its id.