# Spring pageable with specification add more LEFT JOIN on order by joined column

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, specifications

Can anybody explain to me why Spring adds `LEFT JOIN` checking on pageable `Order` using its **specification** feature?

Here is the case:

I want to use Spring specification to generate dynamic query for filtering data and pageable to limit the data. The query is between `UserEntity` and `UserGroupEntity`, and I want to always fetch the `UserGroupEntity` on every query, therefore I add a checking block for `COUNT` and data query. If the query is a query `COUNT` then I use the `Join` object, otherwise I use the `Fetch` object.

```
public static Specification<UserEntity> filtered(final String searchTerm) {

    return new Specification<UserEntity>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<UserEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

            Join<UserEntity, UserGroupEntity> joinUserGroup = null;

            if (QueryHelper.isQueryCount(query)) {

                joinUserGroup = root.join("userGroup");

            } else {

                Fetch<UserEntity, UserGroupEntity> fetchUserGroup = root.fetch("userGroup");
                joinUserGroup = (Join<UserEntity, UserGroupEntity>) fetchUserGroup;
            }


            if (searchTerm != null) {

                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("lowerUsername").as(String.class), "%" + searchTerm.toLowerCase() + "%"));

predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("lowerEmail").as(String.class), "%" + searchTerm.toLowerCase() + "%"));

predicates.add(cb.like(joinUserGroup.get("lowerName").as(String.class), "%" + searchTerm.toLowerCase() + "%"));

                cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }

            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

This is how I call the specification on `UserService`:

```
Order order = new Order(Direction.ASC, "lowerEmail");
Page<UserEntity> pages = userRepository.findAll(filtered(searchTerm), new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(order)));
```

The query is fine when I add an ordering using `UserEntity` column. Here is the generated HQL:

```
select generatedAlias0 from com.example.entity.UserEntity as generatedAlias0 
inner join fetch generatedAlias0.userGroup as generatedAlias1 
order by generatedAlias0.lowerEmail asc
```

But the query becomes strange (because I don't know why) when I use the the column from joined entity for ordering which is `userGroup.lowerName`. By using that column, Spring adds more `LEFT JOIN` in my query and makes it like this:

```
select generatedAlias0 from com.example.entity.UserEntity as generatedAlias0 
left join generatedAlias0.userGroup as generatedAlias1 
inner join fetch generatedAlias0.userGroup as generatedAlias2 
order by generatedAlias1.lowerName asc
```

As I come across the spring-data-JPA code on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L617), I found that the translation from `specification` to `criteria` is done in method `getQuery()`. This method calls other method `toOrders()` from class `QueryUtils` to apply the sort order. Method `toOrders()` finally calls method `getOrCreateJoin()` or `isAlreadyFetched()` which will check the the previous join attribute (the one I made in the specification) which is `userGroup`, but because the join type is not `LEFT JOIN` then Spring adds more join using `LEFT JOIN` in my query.

```
private static Join<?, ?> getOrCreateJoin(From<?, ?> from, String attribute) {

    for (Join<?, ?> join : from.getJoins()) {

        boolean sameName = join.getAttribute().getName().equals(attribute);

        if (sameName && join.getJoinType().equals(JoinType.LEFT)) {
            return join;
        }
    }

    return from.join(attribute, JoinType.LEFT);
}
```

That's what I got from my search on the `spring-data-jpa` code, CMIIW. What is the purpose of the `JoinType.LEFT` actually I still don't understand. Your explanation will be very helpful for me (and us).

Now I think that I will use custom repository to generate dynamic query using JPQL until I understand the reason for that generated query with additional `LEFT JOIN` using `specification` and `pageable`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found the solution and answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43965633/7280115. You may check if it also works for you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.