# Unnecessary Join Queries in Spring Data JPA : PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an spring-boot application which has entities with @OneToMany association.

**ThingType.java**

```
@Entity
public class ThingType {
 @Id
 private String thingTypeId;
 
 @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,mappedBy="thingType",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<Thing> things;
}
```

**Thing.java**

```
@Entity
public class Thing {
 @Id
 private String thingId;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "thingType",nullable = false)
 @JsonIgnore
 private ThingType thingType;
}
```

**ThingTypeRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface ThingTypeRepository {
 @Override
 Optional<ThingType> findById(String s);

 @Query("select t from ThingType t where t.thingTypeId = ?1")
 Optional<ThingType> findThingTypeById(@NonNull String thingTypeId);
}
```

Initially I was using the **findById** method to get a single **ThingType**. It was executing a join between the tables, instead of a simple select query.

After referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949099/spring-data-jpa-unnecessary-left-join) I added *option=false* to **@ManyToOne** annotation & *nullable=false* to **@JoinColumn** in the **Thing.java**. Though It was still executing the join query.
Later I wrote one method with **@Query** annotation, still it is executing the join query.

What might be the solution for this.

**Updated Question**

**ThingTypeController.java**

```
@Autowired
private ThingTypeService thingTypeService;

@RestController
public class ThingController{
 @GetMapping("/{id}")
 public ResponseEntity<Object> getThing(@PathVariable("id") id){
  ThingType thingType = thingTypeService.getThingType(thingTypeId);
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(thingType);
 }
}
```

**ThingTypeService.java**

```
@Service
public class ThingService{
 @Autowired
 private ThingTypeRepository thingTypeRepository;

 public ThingType getThingType(String thingTypeId) {
    ThingType thingType = thingTypeRepository.findThingTypeById(thingTypeId).orElse(null);
    if(thingType == null){
        throw new ResultNotFoundException();
    }
    return thingType;
 }
}
```

Comment: try native query with option true

Comment: Can you provide more details? What's the entire block snippet that calls `findById`? How do you treat the result `ThingType` object?

Comment: `FetchType.EAGER` places a requirement on the persistence provider, but `FetchType.LAZY` is only a hint.  The conditions, if any, under which a persistence provider will avoid fetching a lazy relationship before it is accessed are specific to the persistence provider.

Comment: @DEV, I tried adding native query to true. Still didn't help

Comment: @JohnBollinger, are you saying that Spring Data JPA will behave like this ?

Comment: I don't think Spring provides its own JPA persistence provider, so I think I'm saying that the behavior is outside of Spring's direct control.  More directly, I'm saying that there is no combination of annotations that can *ensure* that the queries actually hitting your database are of the form you say you want.  Even if you found one that worked for you, it might stop working in the future when you change some component of the system.  So if you need that behavior, you should rely on something else, such as a native query.

Comment: @Badhusha what's the exact query that you get and what do you expect as alternative?